# How to make Graphical User interfaces in ROS?

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Can anybody please let me know how to make a graphical user interfaces in ROS? I have heard about qt and rqt. But there is so less documentation available about these. I have also heard rqt_gui. I have to make a user interface for a mobile robot. I was considering using an android app for that. But, if a user interface can be easily built using ROS tools then I think it would be a better option.

Can somebody please help?

Thanks

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/194818/how-to-make-graphical-user-interfaces-in-ros?/) by [ish45](https://answers.ros.org/users/20021/ish45/) on ROS Answers with karma: 151 on 2014-10-12

Post score: 2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I suggest you look at the [rqt/Tutorials](http://wiki.ros.org/rqt/Tutorials) on the wiki.

There is not a standard way to do things on android.

Another option is to use a web interface for which [Robot Web Tools](http://robotwebtools.org/) is a recommended approach.

---

Originally posted by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) with karma: 58457 on 2014-10-12

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [ish45](https://answers.ros.org/users/20021/ish45/) on 2014-10-13**:
Thanks for that. I have looked up at rqt. I would use the WYSIWYG offered by Qt Creator to create the design of the GUI.

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I just made a regular web application and interfaced with the ROS portion of the application using rosbridge/websockets. It worked out pretty well.

---

Originally posted by [kauffeem](https://answers.ros.org/users/40526/kauffeem/) with karma: 11 on 2019-12-03

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Kavya K S](https://answers.ros.org/users/39070/kavya-k-s/) on 2020-02-13**:
Hii, can you share the way you did. it will be usefull for all